# Analysis of shell sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, shellsort

I am reading a book on algorithms it is mentioned on analysis of shell sort algorithm as below:

**The worst-case running time of Shellsort, using Shell's increments, is Theta(n square).**

> The proof requires showing not only an upper bound on the worst-case
>   running time but also showing that there exists some input that
>   actually takes lower bound as Omeaga(n square) time to run. We prove
>   the lower bound first, by constructing a bad case.

My question on above is:

1. why author is mentioning bad case to check for lower bound? I taught to get lower bound we should take best case, 
   Kindly request to clarify above.

Thanks!

Comment: You can ask for upper (Omicron), lower (Omega) and both (Theta) bounds on worst, average, and best cases. In other words, the bound is orthogonal to the case.

Comment: can u please expalin what do u mean by the bound is orthogonal to the case?

Comment: You can have separate Omicron, Omega and Theta bounds for the best, worst, and average cases. Consider an algorithm that is either Omega(n) or O(n log n) for one specific input, Theta(n^2) for all other inputs, except exactly one other input that's either Omega(n^3) or O(n^3 log n). When I say either, maybe it chooses randomly; whatever. It would be pretty straightforward to construct such an algorithm, if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason he is considering both upper bound and lower bound is because he wants to express worst-case time using **Theta(Θ) notation**.

> The theta notation requires you to establish both a upper bound and a
>   lower bound.

Comment: Seems to me he's asking why to check the bad case for a lower bound... why not a good one? As such, not sure this answers his question... true though it is.

Comment: The point is that to prove the worst-case theta complexity, you need a lower bound for the worst-case complexity and an upper bound for the worst-case complexity.  The lower bound is shown directly by exhibiting an example of worst case behaviour, and the upper bound is shown by indirect proof.

Answer (score 0):

To show that something is `Theta(f(n))`, one has to show both an upper and a lower bound, which is what the text is doing.

The claim that "the **worst-case time** is Theta(n square)" requires one to demonstrate both an upper and a lower bound for said **worst-case time**.

Similarly, a statement about the **average-case** time being Theta(f(n)) would require two bounds on the **average-case** time.

And so on.

As @Patrick87 succinctly puts it:

> the bound is orthogonal to the case.

Comment: but for lower bound we should consider best case rather than bad case, why author is considering bad case? For base case we have upper bound am i right

Comment: Seems to me he's asking why to check the bad case for a lower bound... why not a good one? As such, not sure this answers his question... true though it is.

Comment: @venkysmarty: I've expanded the answer in an attempt to further clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Theta is a bounding constraint (both upper and lower).  To show an algorithm has running time Theta(f(n)) you have to establish two things:

1) in the worst case, the algorithm runs in time O(f(n)) for all cases [worst case complexity]

2) The lgorithm must take time Omega(f(n)) [there are real examples that hit the worst case scenario]

You establish the second part by finding particularly bad cases for the algorithm.